# Running a visual studio 2019 c++ code with cryptopp library on raspberrypi for performance analysis

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi-desktop

I've written a code in visual studio 2019 in c++ language and it involves various cryptographic mechanisms. It also includes Elliptic curve library named cryptopp. I want to simulate and test the performance of the code on raspberrypi. Can someone guide me that how i'll be able to do that? How can i test the performance of my already written code in raspberrypi?

Comment: how is compiling and running your code on RPI different from doing this on any other computer?

Comment: Can u please explain? How will it be done? Any links that would be helpful? It would be appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid you are asking a question that's too broad and may be solving a problem that has been solved already: https://github.com/ANSSI-FR/libecc, I hope it helps: they do post benchmarks for RPI too.

Comment: you would compile and run your code on a raspberry pi

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i want to do that. but when i connect the raspberrypi with my laptop and run my code on it, the cryptopp library start giving errors. But when i run my code without raspberrypi, it works well and no errors are found. Then why it gives error with raspberrypi?

Comment: `run my code on it` so, you're running the code, so you managed to compile it. That's a good start. What are these errors you get when you're running your code?

Comment: The errors are about cryptopp library. After connecting to raspberry, it can't detect the libraries. May be it doesn't support cryptopp libraries

Comment: What are the exact errors then? Could you update the question with the steps you've already tried and the exact output you're getting?